# How to change that array of items in JComboBox at runtime

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I add a `JComboBox` to a `JPanel` (in the `JComboBox` constructor I load array of strings). How can I change that array at runtime, to load new items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than pass your values in the constructor, you should create a [`ComboBoxModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html) derived class and pass that to the constructor. A simple example would be [`DefaultComboBoxModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html), but you could create your own if that didn't satisfy your needs. Then you can modify the model and the changes are applied to the [`ComboBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add new items in JComboBox at runtime then use `addItem()` method of JComboBox.

Comment: @Overbose: to remove use `removeItemAt(index)` or `removeItem(obj)`

Comment: see [java docs for JComboBox](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) for more help.